# Unable to access mailbox with mutt on CentOS 6

Tags: mutt

When I run `mutt -f /var/spool/mail/username/Maildir/`,  I get `/var/spool/mail/username/Maildir/ is not a mailbox`.

However, when I run `sudo /var/spool/mail/username/Maildir/` I can view the mailbox.

To test, I ran `chmod 777` on another directory: `

```
chmod 777 /var/spool/mail/testuser/Maildir/
```

When I ran `mutt -f /var/spool/mail/testuser/Maildir/`, I did not get the error message, but the mailbox itself was not displayed (it contains mails). Again, when I did `sudo mutt -f /var/spool/mail/username/Maildir/` I was able to view the mailbox.

```
$ namei -m /var/spool/mail/username
f: /var/spool/mail/username
 dr-xr-xr-x /
 drwxr-xr-x var
 drwxr-xr-x spool
 drwxrwxr-x mail
 drwx------ username
```

Also

```
$ namei -m /var/spool/mail/testuser
f: /var/spool/mail/testuser/
 dr-xr-xr-x /
 drwxr-xr-x var
 drwxr-xr-x spool
 drwxrwxr-x mail
 drwxrwxrwx testuser
```

I'm on CentOS 6.

Edit: The directory owner is a new user I created.

```
$ ls -ld /var/spool/mail/username/
drwx------ 3 postmail postmail 4096 Jul 14 15:11 /var/spool/mail/username/
```

Comment: Who says? After running what command? On what operating system? Please [edit] your question and give us more information. We can't help if you don't explain what you are doing in more detail.

Comment: Hi, I've edited the question

Comment: Thanks for the edit. But please show us the exact command you ran (all of them, including the `chmod`; what directory did you run the chmod on? ), and the exact error messages received. Also, as I said before, we need to know your operating system. Is this Linux? Which one? Unix? Which one? Solaris? macOS? BSD? Also, please show us the output of `namei -m /var/spool/mail/username/`.

Comment: What user owns the `/var/spool/mail/username` directory? Only the owner has access to it. What is the output of `ls -ld /var/spool/mail/username`?

Comment: I've added the info. I thought only the owner having permission  might be the issue and changed the permissions of `testuser` but ran into the other problem I mentioned. I changed the permission of `username` directory to 777 and ran into the same issue - `/var/spool/mail/username/Maildir is not a mailbox.`

Comment: Yes, but you ran `mutt -f /var/spool/mail/testuser/Maildir/` as `username` not `testuser`, right? Doesn't it work if you do `sudo -u testuser mutt -f /var/spool/mail/testuser/Maildir/`? And what if you just run `sudo chown username /var/spool/mail/username`? I am not posting this as an answer because I'm not 100% sure that those should be owned by their users.

Comment: I'm sorry I should have added this detail - these are virtual users.